# Permitting params with custom keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a model names TeamInvite that I am trying to create a team_invite_params method for.

When I created the migration for the table, because I wanted to keep track of the sender and recipient, I opted for the custom field names

> sender_id

and

> recipient_id

to not mix up which user was which.

Anyway, when I try and permit the parameters for a team_invite, I am having trouble telling the permit method that the

**Edit:**

> "team_invite"=>{"user"=>"2"}

is in fact what should go under *recipient_id*. All the methods I have tried either don't work or end up passing no value at all.

Controller

```
def create
  @team_invite = TeamInvite.new(team_invite_params)
end
```

Model

```
  class TeamInvite < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  end
```

Params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0QLA9YiTu9nAf6QJLX5rg0DWa7CAMjqGOlUBICbcL8Ucs2DsCDgGBnhiDXPa/ot8DK0xwTR1D7MASu4/9tVj0w==", "team_invite"=>{"recipient_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Save Team invite"}
```

View (if it matters):

```
<%= form_for :team_invite, url: team_invites_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :recipient_id, User.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, include_blank: false %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Migration:

```
class CreateTeamInvite < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :team_invites do |t|
      t.references :team, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :recipient_id
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
params.permit(:team_invites => [ :user ]) #or whatever other nested team_invite params you want to pass in.
```

Docs for strong_params here: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: But I need to assign it specifically to "user_id" because there are other fields that need to be permitted as well.

Comment: You would do that in your controller action e.g. `@team_invite.user_id = params[:team_invite][:user]`

Comment: I tried that but recipient_id is still coming up null.

Comment: Gonna need some more code in that case. Can you post your controller action and the params that are being sent with the request form your logs?

Comment: Updated in question. I could hack my way to a solution, but I'm really interested in how to do this properly.